# Update three.js Group after it was added to the scene on runtime

Tags: three.js

I have a THREE.Group(); in my scene and at runtime i want to add more to this group but it doesn't get updatet or better i cannot see the sprite that i added on runtime. The sprite is in the group but not rendered.

How can i update a THREE.Group();?

Example Code to clarify my problem. Not really running i know.

```
var systemGroup = new THREE.Group();
init();
animate();

function init() {
    //add something to systemGroup like multiple meshes
    systemGroup.add(mesh);
    scene.add(systemGroup);
}

function render() {
    scene.updateMatrixWorld();
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
}

function addMore(x,y,z){
    var map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "sprite.png" );
    var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: map, color: 0xffffff, fog: true } );
    var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( material );
    sprite.position.set(x,y,z);
    systemGroup.add(sprite);
    //Here how do i update the group so that the mesh is in the scene?
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are showing is adding the same mesh over and over again.
As the mesh is already in the group, it doesn't change anything.

What you seem to want is to `clone()` the mesh and add it at a different position.

Like this:

```
var group = new THREE.Group()
scene.add(group);

document.body.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  var clone = mesh.clone()
  clone.position.set(-100 + Math.random()*200, 0, 0)
  group.add(mesh)
})
```

No need to update the group with anything else.

Comment: thank you for your help. I was searching a lot for my question but it seems that my code has simply a problem and is not able to add it to the group beacuse something different is wrong. I hope i can find it. Code is to big to post it anywhere. Thanks